# Numpy build fails with cannot import multiarray

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy, homebrew

I'm using homebrew python on Mavericks, trying to build numpy 1.8.  Unfortunately, when I try to install numpy, I get the following error: https://gist.github.com/ngoldbaum/8592039

I'm able to build numpy 1.7.2 with `pip install numpy==1.7.2`, but numpy 1.8 always fails to build with the same traceback.

Comment: Maybe it's conflict with your system environment. Try to install numpy in the [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: It seems I'm able to build numpy in a virtualenv.  Any idea how I can track down what's causing the conflict in my system environment?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

on Mac:

1.) remove these 2 folders manually:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.10.4.dist-info/
```

notice: `pip uninstall numpy` didn't work for me, I had to remove numpy manually.

2.) re-install numpy: `pip install numpy`

Comment: Work for windows too. Nice solution!

Comment: I tried this solution but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using Anaconda with python 2.7 and numpy 1.14.0

Comment: on windows, after doing the the above, don't forget to restart spyder

Comment: Mine was fine with just `brew uninstall` and `brew install`, so I guess everyone's milage may vary

Comment: Worked for me too (in a Windows 10 environment). For what it's worth, I installed numpy using `python -m pip install numpy`

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by doing `brew uninstall python`, deleting the contents of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, reinstalling python, and then rebuilding numpy.

Comment: A more fine-grained solution is to look for previous numpy installations (e.g. look for 'numpy/__init__.py' or multiarray.*) and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue doing this:
Python.exe .\lib\site-packages\easy_install.py

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling numpy and reinstalling numpy using pip -

```
pip3 uninstall numpy

pip3 install numpy
```