# Numpy fails to import multiarray jupyter notebook/anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I've been struggling with this for the past three days.  This is in Jupyter Notebook in the Anaconda 3 (32 bit) package for windows. This is the error that is spit out at my when I run import numpy as np

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ee716103900> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15
```

###############################################################################

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, zeros
     13 from .ufunclike import isneginf, isposinf

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     24 Original error was: %s
     25 """ % (exc,)
---> 26     raise ImportError(msg)
     27 
     28 for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be 
found.
```

After all of this I've used both conda uninstall numpy and manually removed the folder on separate tries.  I just want to get back to machine learning.  Any help that could be provided would be great.  This is after I've used the conda root addition.

-Thanks

Comment: Go to this post.
Look for mac: Solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324426/numpy-build-fails-with-cannot-import-multiarray