# Python ImportError "cannot import name 'multiarray'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to simply import numpy into a python script (called "MatPlotLib.py using PyCharm) and I'm receiving this odd error.  It worked fine, but then I started messing around with Jupyter.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python, then a system restore, but nothing seems to be working.  I think reinstalling numpy will do the trick, though I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm not sure what the error means by "a numpy git repo, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you need any additional information please let me know.  Find the full error below! :)

Thank you so much in advanced.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
>   C:/Users/Alex/PycharmProjects/2017_Research/Automation/MatPlotLib.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from . import multiarray ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Alex/PycharmProjects/2017_Research/Automation/MatPlotLib.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import numpy   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy__init__.py",
>   line 142, in 
>       from . import add_newdocs   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib__init__.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from .type_check import *   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       import numpy.core.numeric as _nx   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:  Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a
>   failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try
>   `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control). 
>   Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Reinstall numpy....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324426/numpy-build-fails-with-cannot-import-multiarray  This may help.

Comment: I got the same error after installing 32 bit anaconda repo's pandas+numpy+scipy on 64 bit win 7, which was solved with correct versioning, so I would say recheck and reinstall.